# functional requirement specification for the following abstract

Tags: documentation

can any one give me the functional requirements documentation for the reservation tracking system ,it is going to be implemented in asp.net and the details are as follows,

1)The main theme of this application is gathering reservations from different clients and updated in particular intervals of time to the Fitzserver then these reservations will  be send to the particular driver.

2) Then driver information is retrieved through mobile application using webservice and updated in the Fitzserver.

3) The information of driver from Fitzserver is send to the client as link to email.

Comment: wouldn't your post count as the requirement specification?

Answer (score 2):

No, nobody can unless they are either the user/stakeholder of a similar system or the developer/architect of a similar system.

You should execute the requirements process. Talk to the endusers, write down what they expect.

Examples/guidelines on how to go forward:

http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/index.htm
See Practices > Technical Practices > Use Case Driven Development

http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Technical_writing_specification